# How to get POST parameters in Laravel 5.2.45

Tags: laravel, post, controller, http-post

I am posting

```
http://localhost/gos-twilio/server-laravel/public/login
```

in Fiddler. I am putting a random variable named `kurac` and I put in it value 345. I cannot seem to get this value. This is signature of my function in controller, and indeed, that method IS being reached:

```
protected function login(Request $r)
```

I tried putting these pieces of code (none of them worked) inside the function:

```
error_log($r->post());
error_log($r->all());
error_log($r->input());
```

All of them give empty array as output. Only one that gives actual output is:

1. error_log($r)

but it is almost useless since it is just an object (I can see a huge output in the logs). However I see in it the 345 of kurac value.
I tried using this for Request declaration in the controller file:

```
use Request;
```

and

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

and

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

none worked. Any advice? Thanks in advance for the idiotic downvotes on a question that I do not know the answer to.

Answer (score -1):

It was a error in way I sed Fiddler. The variables has to be put in the parameters tab, not in header tab. Doh. Resolved.